# JMeter Multiple Log Files from Command Line

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm running JMeter through jenkins for performance testing using the command line options. I already write to one jtl file when I do the command, such as:

java -jar path to Jmeter -n -t jmx file -l log file

I would like to also put the results into another log file stored in another location, but I can't get it to work by putting another path after the -l command or putting in a second -l. Is there anyway to do this simply?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check these options. you should use the option '-j'. It works fine for me.

```
-n This specifies JMeter is to run in non-gui mode 
-t [name of JMX file that contains the Test Plan]. 
-l [name of JTL file to log sample results to]. 
-j [name of JMeter run log file]. 
-r Run the test in the servers specified by the JMeter property "remote_hosts" 
-R [list of remote servers] Run the test in the specified remote servers
```